# Getting individuals values from dynamic created listview

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hello guys i have a question to ask. How do i retrieve the certain values that a user clicks on for example if the users clicks the third link in the dynamic created listview, it will be able to retrieve the value  47  and retrieve the value 44 if user click the first link and so on. Below is the source code

SUPDBL (Superior Double/Twin)

#### - Rate Inclusive Of Breakfast. 
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
- FREE WiFi Internet Access.

#### Price: $160.00 154152

DLXDBL (Deluxe Double/Twin)

#### - Rate Inclusive Of Breakfast. 
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
- FREE WiFi Internet Access.
- Complimentary 02 bottles drinking water.

#### Price: $175.00 154518

CCRTWIN (Premium Double/Twin)

#### -Rate Inclusive Of Breakfast. 
-Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
-Free flow of coffee & tea at Premium Lounge. 
-Complimentary Welcome Drink & Fruit Platter.     -Free Unlimited Usage Of WiFi Internet Access.    -Complimentary 02 Bottles Drinking Water In The Room.                                                 -Rooms Located On Higher Floor With Paranomic View Of Kuching City.                                  -Room Is Newly Equiped With LCD TV.

#### Price: $220.00 154884

FML (Family Room)

#### - Rate Inclusive Of Breakfast for 03 adults or 02 adults & 02 Children.
- Room With 01 King-Bed & 01 Single Bed.
- FREE WiFi Internet Access.
- Complimentary 02 bottles drinking water.

#### Price: $205.00 155250

ROOMONLY (Superior Room Only - Promotion)

#### - Rate is without Breakfast.
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
- FREE WiFi Internet Access.

#### Price: $145.00 157957

3D2NSUP (Superior Room 3Days/2Night Special)

#### - Minimum 02 night stay at our Superior Room
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
- Rate include daily buffet breakfast for up to 02 person
- Free WiFi Internet Access

#### Price: $150.00 158323

ROOMONLY (Deluxe Room Only - Promotion)

#### - Rate is without breakfast
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds
- FREE WiFi Internet Access
- Complimentary 02 bottles drinking water

#### Price: $160.00 158689

3D2NDLX (Deluxe Room 3Days/2Nights Special)

#### - Minimum 02 nights stay at our Deluxe Room
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds.
- Rate include daily buffet breakfast for up to 02 person
- FREE WiFi Internet Access
- Complimentary 02 bottles of Drinking Water in the room

#### Price: $165.00 159055

ROOMONLY (SUPERIOR SUPER SALE)

#### - Rate is without breakfast
- Room With 01 Double-Bed or 02 Single-Beds
- FREE WiFi Internet Access

#### Price: $100.00 174897

```
  <div data-role="content">
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function test(e) {
          $('#divContent ul li lblSeq').each(function () {
              alert($(this).html());
          });
      }
  </script>
```

code behind file 
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            divContent.InnerHtml = this.BindHtml();
        }

```
}
protected string BindHtml() 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var list = GetRateList();
    foreach(RateType r in list)
    {
        string sr = string.Format("<ul data-role='listview' onclick='test(this);' data-inset='true' data-theme='e'><li><a href='Room.aspx'<h3>{1} ({2}) </h3><h3>  {3} </h3><h3>{4} <span id='lblSeq' style='visibility:hidden; '>{0}</span></h3> </a></li></ul>"
          , r.SeqNo, r.ShortCode, r.Title, r.Description , String.Format( "Price: {0:c}",r.Rate) );
        sb.Append(sr);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

protected List<RateType> GetRateList()
{
    String lblCheckInDate = Request.Cookies["CheckInDate"].Value;
    DateTime CheckInDate = DateTime.Parse(lblCheckInDate);


  return RateTypeService.GetRateTypeList(13, CheckInDate);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick()  event for li tag and pass the values to function what you want.

Comment: ok i did used that but however i can only manage to retrieve the first value only whenever i clicked on any of the links

Comment: @user1381205 I can't understand . If you post some code then I can give better solution for your issue.

Comment: @user1381205 How do you bind data to list view?

Answer (score 0):

Check like this:

add this line after

```
 foreach(RateType r in list) 
{ 
    string param ="'"+r.SeqNo+"'";
    string sr = string.Format("<ul data-role='listview' onclick='test("+param +");' data-inset='true' data-theme='e'><li><a href='Room.aspx'<h3>{1} ({2}) </h3><h3>  {3} </h3><h3>{4} <span id='lblSeq' style='visibility:hidden; '>{0}</span></h3> </a></li></ul>" 
      , r.SeqNo, r.ShortCode, r.Title, r.Description , String.Format( "Price: {0:c}",r.Rate) ); 
    sb.Append(sr); 
}
```

And retrive value

```
function test(code){
```

alert(code);
}

Comment: ok thank the values now display but however it does not alert the (code) and jumps straight to the other webforms

Comment: @user1381205_ It jumps to other web form because , <li><a href='Room.aspx'></a></li> and  change to   <li><a href='#'></a></li>

Comment: @user1381205 Is yours issue fixed..?

Comment: Yup it is fixed because of the single quotes and the double quotes